# I want to check in a list with dict for same keys and if i have same keys to merge the dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

i want ot compare only with key type and if key type is same i want to merge the dictionaries that have the same key['TYPE]:

```
list_1 = [{'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'YOB': [['2010', '2015']]}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'DWT': [[360000, 486000]]}, {'TYPE': ['barge'], 'DWT': [[3800, 6300], [4000, 5000]]}]
```

and i want this result:

```
[{'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'YOB': [['2010', '2015']],'DWT': [[360000, 486000]]}, {'TYPE': ['barge'], 'DWT': [[3800, 6300], [4000, 5000]]}]
```

Comment: And if you do it, what does it give ?

Comment: what do you mean? i want to convert the following list into the result format

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: nothing i dont know how to do it..is it possible to tell me the way?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# list_1 = [{'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'YOB': [['2010', '2015']]}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'DWT': [[360000, 486000]]}, {'TYPE': ['barge'], 'DWT': [[3800, 6300], [4000, 5000]]}]
list_1 = [{'TYPE': ['bc']}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'DWT': [[10000, 15000]]}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo']}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'COB': ['japan'], 'YOB': [['2010', '2015']]}] 
temp = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if i!=0:
        if list_1[i]["TYPE"] == list_1[i-1]["TYPE"]:
            keys_to_add =list(list_1[i].keys())
            keys_to_add.remove("TYPE")
            for k in keys_to_add:
                temp[-1][k] = list_1[i][k]
        else:
            temp.append(list_1[i])
    else:
        temp.append(list_1[i])

print(temp)

>> [{'TYPE': ['bc']},
 {'TYPE': ['general cargo'],
  'DWT': [[10000, 15000]],
  'COB': ['japan'],
  'YOB': [['2010', '2015']]}]
```

Comment: My friend i want to see a case that i have a problem. in this case the following code doesnt play:
[{'TYPE': ['bc']}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'DWT': [[10000, 15000]]}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo']}, {'TYPE': ['general cargo'], 'COB': ['japan'], 'YOB': [['2010', '2015']]}]

Comment: is it possible to tell me the way?